# How to fetching JSON data record by record using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to fetch huge of `JSON data`, Its taking time to load and moreover I am trying offline storage process into my app. So right now I am doing load all `JSON data` and store into plist then I will get and fetching on `tableview.` The problem is Its taking more time.

I need to load first five `records` after click `pulldown refresh` need to load another five. Please help me and post some code for my problem.

Comment: add one more key in your request "index" send index 1 first time and get 5 record after if user pull to refresh increase value of index + 1 and then call webservice again , tell php developer that send result multiple of index
Ex. if you send index 1 then 1*5 result , index 2 * 5 and get 10 result

Comment: please post some sample code. We cant change the services because API's working some other environment.@suthar

Comment: You should create a new API or add pagination parameters to the API. Also, use Core Data so you don't have everything loaded in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the fetchLimit in fetchRequest.

`NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"entityName"];
    request.predicate = nil;
    request.fetchLimit = 100;`

Hope this helps